# PHP While Loop Dynamic SESSION Variables

Tags: php, while-loop

Creating dynamic `$_SESSION` variables with `while` statement to print dates from database. Only need dates `Tuesday` and `Friday` to print.

Achieving this by getting weekday with `date()` and `strtotime()`:

```
$d = 0;//create dynamic numbers
while($mydate = mysqli_fetch_array($myweekdatesQ)){$d++;

//get weekday of date
$weekday =date('l', strtotime($mydate['event_date']));

if($weekday ==='Tuesday'){
$t = 't_'.$d;
echo $_SESSION[$t] = $mydate['event_date'];
}

if($weekday ==='Friday'){
$f = 'f_'.$d;
echo $_SESSION[$f] = $mydate['event_date'];
}
}
```

Works pretty well, but small problem as it prints:

```
$_SESSION[t1];
$_SESSION[f2];
$_SESSION[t3];
$_SESSION[f4];
$_SESSION[t5];
$_SESSION[f6];
$_SESSION[t7];
$_SESSION[f8];
```

However, variable `$d` can never be less than 1 and more than 4. Final result should be:

```
$_SESSION[t1];
$_SESSION[t2];
$_SESSION[t3];
$_SESSION[t4];

$_SESSION[f1];
$_SESSION[f2];
$_SESSION[f3];
$_SESSION[f4];
```

**How to make this work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two dynamic numbers:

```
$d = 0;//create dynamic numbers for $t
$x = 0;//create dynamic numbers for $f
while($mydate = mysqli_fetch_array($myweekdatesQ)) {

    //get weekday of date
    $weekday =date('l', strtotime($mydate['event_date']));

    if($weekday ==='Tuesday') {
        $d++;
        $t = 't_'.$d;
        echo $_SESSION[$t] = $mydate['event_date'];
    }

    if($weekday ==='Friday') {
        $x++;
        $f = 'f_'.$x;
        echo $_SESSION[$f] = $mydate['event_date'];
    }
}
```